# How to increase upload video file size in php?

Tags: php, video, upload, size

I change the value but it's not working, how I upload a 50mb video file with 15 mint duration?   I have no php.ini file

```
 $max_allowed_size = $system['max_video_size'] * 5120;
  
            // prepare uploads directory
            $folder = 'videos';
            $directory = $folder.'/'. date('Y') . '/' . date('m') . '/';

            if($_POST["multiple"] == "true") {

                // prepare files
                $files = array();
                foreach($_FILES['file'] as $key => $val) {
                    for($i=0; $i < count($val); $i++) {
                        $files[$i][$key] = $val[$i];
                    }
                }
                $return_files = array();
                $files_num = count($files);
```

I changed the value 5120 but I can't upload over 2mb video file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in folder file: .user.ini with

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 200M
```

Or test file size

```
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > $bytes){ // upload ... }
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 0):

To increaes file upload size in PHP, you need to modify the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size variable’s in your php.ini file.

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Then after don't forget to run below command

```
service apache2 restart
```